# Pointing Liferay EE database via Liferay Community Edition

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

bHi All,

I have Liferay Enterprise Edition installed which is pointing to Postgres database.

Now, I have another Liferay Community Edition which I want to point to the Liferay Enterprise Edition database copy.

When I start the Community version it gives error like no user exists with the primary id 83498XX. But when I dump the Liferay EE database the users are there but with different primary id.

I just wanted to know is it possible to make the Community edition to point to Enterprise Edition database and make it work?

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, that won't work. Both will register as different versions in the database - where EE is a higher version number than CE. Once you've upgraded to the EE version, CE will cease to run from the same database.

Moreover, some of the data for users is read from the full text index - which must match your database content. So even if you get it to work, you'll have to keep the index in sync. This *might* be the actual problem that you're talking about in your question, but I'm not sure.

However, as it is not designed to work this way anyway, it's not important to find the concrete issue in this case. Just don't do it.